# Node Red: Can I feed in a URL into the http request node rather than hardcoding it within the node

Tags: httprequest, node-red

I have a regular http request node with a function node in front of it that feeds it the header information. Within the http request node, there is a field to specify the URL.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to feed in the URL (maybe also through a function node?) into the http request node, so that I can query a list of URL's rather than having to paste it in every time.

I tried to set the URL in the http request to message.child, but that does not work.

Here is my flowset up for reference:

> [{"id":"de791b20.2ae648","type":"http
>   request","z":"916b3055.b3f1e","name":"","method":"GET","ret":"txt","url":"someurl","tls":"","x":425.2000274658203,"y":228,"wires":[["79e9579b.c337f8","5174250e.88629c"]]},{"id":"a668fd6c.894bf","type":"function","z":"916b3055.b3f1e","name":"","func":"msg.headers
>   = {\n    \"Authorization\" : XXX  \n \n\nreturn msg; \n\n\n","outputs":1,"noerr":3,"x":284.5000305175781,"y":239.60000610351562,"wires":[["de791b20.2ae648"]]},{"id":"5174250e.88629c","type":"http
>   response","z":"916b3055.b3f1e","name":"response","x":605.2000427246094,"y":275.0000457763672,"wires":[]},{"id":"79e9579b.c337f8","type":"debug","z":"916b3055.b3f1e","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"payload","x":620.2000427246094,"y":223.400146484375,"wires":[]},{"id":"7f6783ac.6ea06c","type":"inject","z":"916b3055.b3f1e","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":135.1999969482422,"y":239,"wires":[["a668fd6c.894bf"]]}]

Answer (score 2):

To set the URL dynamically, leave the field blank in the node configuration then pass in `msg.url`.

The info sidebar for the request node describes what properties you can set dynamically.